# ansible: Is there something like with_fileglobs for files on remote machine?

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I'm trying to turn [these](https://github.com/callumacrae/dotfiles/blob/master/install/zsh.sh#L12-L18) lines into something I can put in an ansible playbook:

```
# Install Prezto files
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
files=( "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}"/.zprezto/runcoms/!(README.md) )
for rcfile in "${files[@]}"; do
    [[ -f $rcfile ]] && ln -s "$rcfile" "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.${rcfile##*/}"
done
```

So far I've got the following:

```
- name: Link Prezto files
  file: src={{ item }} dest=~ state=link
  with_fileglob:
    - ~/.zprezto/runcoms/z*
```

I know it isn't the same, but it would select the same files: except with_fileglob looks on the host machine, and I want it to look on the remote machine.

Is there any way to do this, or should I just use a shell script?

Answer (score 27):

A clean Ansible way of purging unwanted files matching a glob is:

```
- name: List all tmp files
  find:
    paths: /tmp/foo
    patterns: "*.tmp"
  register: tmp_glob

- name: Cleanup tmp files
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{ tmp_glob.files }}"
```

Comment: Just what I needed to get me in the right direction for a chmod on a glob pattern!

Comment: This should be The Answer

Comment: In Ansible 4, you'll need to use `with_items: "{{ tmp_glob.files | map(attribute='path') }}"` (as well as FQCNs)

Answer (score 6):

Bruce P's solution works, but it requires an addition file and gets a little messy. Below is a pure ansible solution.

The first task grabs a list of filenames and stores it in files_to_copy. The second task appends each filename to the path you provide and creates symlinks.

```
- name: grab file list
  shell: ls /path/to/src
  register: files_to_copy
- name: create symbolic links
  file:
    src: "/path/to/src/{{ item }}"
    dest: "path/to/dest/{{ item }}"
    state: link
  with_items: files_to_copy.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 2):

The file module does indeed look on the server where ansible is running for files when using with_fileglob, etc.  Since you want to work with files that exist solely on the remote machine then you could do a couple things.  One approach would be to copy over a shell script in one task then invoke it in the next task.  You could even use the fact that the file was copied as a way to only run the script if it didn't already exist:

```
- name: Copy link script
  copy: src=/path/to/foo.sh
        dest=/target/path/to/foo.sh
        mode=0755
  register: copied_script

- name: Invoke link script
  command: /target/path/to/foo.sh
  when: copied_script.changed
```

Another approach would be to create an entire command line that does what you want and invoke it using the shell module:

```
- name: Generate links
  shell: find ~/.zprezto/runcoms/z* -exec ln -s {} ~ \;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `with_lines` to accomplish this:

```
- name: Link Prezto files
  file: src={{ item }} dest=~ state=link
  with_lines: ls ~/.zprezto/runcoms/z*
```

Comment: In my case, I ran it and it still picked the pattern files from the SOURCE machine and not from the target (inventory host machine).

Comment: Oops, I didn't catch that this was for the remote machine.